# Why is mice imputation giving me different results after updating R version?

Tags: r, version, r-mice

After moving from a computer running R 3.4.0 to a computer running R 3.5.0, the exact same code is giving me different results for my imputation using the mice package, which has changed from version 2.46.0 to 3.3.0. Specifically, some (possibly all) imputed values are different, but more noticeably, two columns out of approximately 50 did not get imputed at all. These columns have approximately 50 mostly unique known values and 3700 missing values. There were two other columns that had fewer known values and they were successfully imputed. Approximately 20 columns total were missing values, all of which were numeric, and except for the two previously mentioned, all were imputed successfully. I set the random seed.

I am new to the field of data science, but I suspect this has to do with the mice package version. Unfortunately I have not been able to find any information that explains why this might happen or how to correct it.

```
#Pseudocode
#Function for determining method for mice, based on data type of each feature (skip dates)
myMeth <- function(myData) {
    featureType <- sapply(myData,function(feature) {class(feature)[1]})
    return(for each datatype in featureType, character types get "polyreg",
        numeric types get "pmm", date types get "")
}

#Perform imputation
#I exclude features with exactly 2 unique values because it was causing
#    a "failed to converge" fatal error in R 3.4.0
myImputation <- mice(myData, meth=myMeth(myData), pred=quickpred(myData, mincor=0.1,
    minpuc=0.1, exclude=c(featuresWithDateType, featuresWithLessThan3UniqueValues)),
    m=myTotalImputations, maxit=myMaxIterations, seed=1)
```

Comment: The mice package does have a github page where you can directly report problems to the package authors: https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/issues

Comment: Did you set your seed?

Comment: ekstroem- Yes, you can see in my code-y pseudocode that my last argument when calling mice is "seed=1". I also have a seed set at the very beginning of my script. When running the code, I get the same result every time, differing only when I switch versions, so I'm sure the seed is working.